# This function or variable may be unsafe visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I got a problem on visual studio. 
I try to use the localtime function from "time.h".

Visual studio tells me it's an unsafe function. However, I have tu use this one for my school exercice. I saw that you can disable this unsafe error by going in the project properties, build tab, and check "enable unsafe code".

Nevertheless, I don't have a build tab, as you can see there : 
http://puu.sh/4NkYC.png

I'm using windows 7 and visual studio 2012 Ultimate. It looks like the "build tab" and "enable unsafe code" has vanished :/
Maybe you know how to fix that ?

thank's a lot :)

Comment: You're thinking of C#'s `unsafe` keyword, which is completely different.

Comment: @SLaks - what is the **portable**, "safe" variant of `localtime`?

Answer (score 35):

You can switch off the warning using the following directive:

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996) //_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Answer (score 15):

`localtime` is marked unsafe by the MS-Compiler because it returns a pointer to a statically allocated `struct tm`. This is obviously a bad idea.
Therefore, `localtime_s` was invented by Microsoft, which takes a pointer to a `struct tm` allocated by you
`struct tm timeinfo;

localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);`

Use this (and have your program be Microsoft specific) or switch off the warning by defining `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.

Answer (score 15):

Visual Studio (VS) compiler gives this error. It's simple to get rid of this problem.

1. Go to your VS context menu **Project>Properties**.
2. Click **Configuration>Properties>C/C++>Preprocessor**.
3. Edit **Preprocessor Definitions** and add *_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS* last empty line.

This compile warning will be gone.

Answer (score 4):

`unsafe` is part of C# not C++. For example these [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0.aspx) clearly say

> /unsafe (C# Compiler Options)

at the top

In C++, visual studio will complain about functions it regards as *unsecure* and suggest you `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` if you don't want lots of warnings, for example

`localtime` might give you the following:

> warning C4996: 'localtime': This function or variable may be unsafe.
>   Consider using localtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
char counter_str[10];

int main()
{ 
  time_t my_time = time(NULL)// declaring argument of time();
  sprintf(counter_str,ctime(&my_time));//fetch current time
  printf(counter_str);

}
```

Comment: As this may answer the question, would be great to include some short explanation or description to the provided code.

Comment: #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Answer (score 0):

The portable, "safe" version of `localtime` is `localtime_r`.  Like Microsoft's `localtime_s` mentioned in Henno's answer, `localtime_r` takes an additional argument which is a pointer to the `struct tm` to fill in, rather than using a shared, statically-allocated one as `localtime` does.
Example:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm tmbuf;
localtime_r(&t, &tmbuf);
```