# scanf: This function or variable may be unsafe

Tags: c

I'm studying the `scanf` function.

I made the code in the example the same way and ran it but I got the following error message.

I checked the spelling and the format specifiers in the printer function but I couldn't find the solution.

Has anyone solved this problem?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    scanf("%d", a);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead.
```

Comment: Ignore this and put `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the very top of the c files where you use `scanf`.

Comment: Note that it should be `scanf("%d", &a);`, as it expects the address of `a`.

Comment: Not related to the question: [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) expects the addresses of the variables to store the read values into. Try `scanf("%d", &a);`

Comment: Alternatively, switch from MSVC to more or less any other C compiler.  This would be a win for you in multiple ways.

Comment: **Close voter**:  while the missing `&` is definitely a problem here, the main problem the question is about will not be solved by putting the `&`.

Comment: C std functions aren't secure by design. They're prone to be vulnerable to buffer overflow attacks, for instance. That's why you get that warning.

Comment: `scanf("%d", ...)` is completely unsafe, and the behavior is undefined on certain inputs. (eg, if INT_MAX on your platform is 2147483647 and the input stream contains 21474836470).   You should forget that `scanf` exists and parse the input using something else.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, I agree. OTOH `scanf` is fine for quick and dirty school stuff/simple leaning projects/other test stuff etc.  It should however never be used in real world production software.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The behavior is undefined on certain inputs. It may be important in some situations and not so important in others. It is not a reason to discard a tool.

Comment: @n.m There are many other reasons to avoid `scanf`.  But whether or not you choose to use `scanf`, you *must* abandon all bare uses of `"%s"` or `"%d"` and ensure that width modifiers are always used.  Or accept that your software is buggy.

Comment: @은은솔 It's true that `scanf` is not a particularly "safe" function.  But Microsoft's allegedly-safer version, `scanf_s`, isn't much safer.  So the consensus advice is as suggested in Jabberwocky's comment: define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, to silence the warnings, and move on.

Comment: @WilliamPursell No, I don't have to always produce software that is able to handle arbitrary inputs or fail gracefully. Only if the specification calls for it. The specification of a student's assignment is unlikely to demand that.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` *is* inherently unsafe to use, especially with this variant:

```
scanf( "%s", str );
```

Suppose `str` is an array sized to hold no more than 10 characters.

`scanf` doesn't know that - as written, it doesn't know that `str` can only hold that many characters.  If your input is 100 characters long, `scanf` will happily write those extra 90 characters to the memory *after* `str`, clobbering anything that's there and causing all kinds of mayhem.

You can avoid this by specifying a max input length as part of the format:

```
scanf( "%9s", str );
```

but unlike `printf` you can't specify this length with a `*` and additional argument:

```
printf( "%*s", 10, str );
```

It either has to be hardcoded, or the format string has to be built dynamically:

```
char fmt[20];
sprintf( fmt, "%%%zus", sizeof str );
scanf( fmt, str );
```

It isn't so bad for numeric input (although it will bite you in the ass there too if you aren't careful), but for text input it's absolutely unsafe. For that, it's better to ditch `scanf` entirely and use `fgets` instead:

```
if ( fgets( str, sizeof str, stdin ) )
{
  // process input
}
```

`scanf` is great when you know your input is well-behaved, which means it should never be used for interactive input.

As for getting rid of the warning, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321804/this-function-or-variable-may-be-unsafe-visual-studio) has a number of suggestions.